# Xamarin iOS - MVVMCross : Unable to connect button in custom cell with command in ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross

I am using MVVMCross, for my Xamarin iOS project. I am using a button inside the cell. I want to connect it to viewModel through command, but for some reason, I am not able to successfully bind them.

Can someone please have a look and let me know where I am doing wrong or what updates should I make to my code.

**View:**

```
public partial class MyCell : MvxCollectionViewCell 
{
        public PostImageCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
            this.DelayBind(() =>
            {
                    var bSet = this.CreateBindingSet<MyCell, SomeViewModel>();
                    bSet.Bind(Btn).To(vm => vm.EditPhotoCommand);
                    bSet.Apply();
            });
        }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class SomeViewModel : BaseCoreViewModel
{
        public SomeViewModel()
        {
         editPhotoCommand = new BaseMvxCommand(DoShow);
        }

        public ICommand EditPhotoCommand { get { return editPhotoCommand; } }

        private void DoShow()
        { 
          //
        }
}
```

I kept some breakpoints and realized that when the `MyCell` constructor is being called, the code inside `this.DelayBind()` is not being hit, so i tried removing `this.DelayBind` but still no use.
Whenever I click on the button inside the cell, its not binding to the command inside ViewModel

Comment: Does your `Btn` control inherit from `UIButton`? If not what type is it?

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r Yes, Its derived from UIButton

Comment: Azhar Ali could you provide a sample that replicates this issue?

Comment: Could you share your xib/nib file? You can test if this is where the issue is, if you override `AwakeFromNib` in your `MyCell ` and manually add your button to the cell's content view `public override void AwakeFromNib()
{
    base.AwakeFromNib();

    ContentView.AddSubview(Btn);
}`

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r How can I share my xib file here ?

Comment: You should be able to open it in a text editor like notepad++ and then just copy the content. At the core it is just xml. Did the override `AwakeFromNib` I suggested above have any effect on the button?

Comment: hmm, i can not find anything wrong in the nib

Comment: Can I send you a sample, do you think you can have a look ?

Comment: Sure, if can supply a github link to a sample that reproduces the behaviour will I check it out

Answer (score 0):

Probably do something like below in your ViewModel and then bind as bSet.Bind(Btn).To(vm => vm.ClickCommand); I have your button is properly set on the view. I have a sample working right now with button on tableviewcell.

```
    private MvxCommand _clickCommand;
    public ICommand ClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            _clickCommand = _clickCommand ?? new MvxCommand(Hit);
            return _clickCommand;
        }
    }

    private void Hit()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Tapped Click Me");
        //System. .WriteLine ("Tapped Click Me");
    }
```